# Conducting different tests on a website at once

Tags: ab-testing

We have our own A/B test software which works this way:

- Every time a user visits a page with a test, he gets a cookie marker.
- For variant A in test one it may look like this: test1_a
- For test 2 and variant b: test2_b etc.
- Once a user makes a purchase, it is written to the A/B panel for the test connected to the marker. For example, if user had the "test1_a" marker, the Variant A in the test 1 will get +1 conversion once a user purchases something.

If we run different tests on a website at once, a user gets multiple markers if he visits different test pages, like:

test1_a, test2_b, etc

After that if user makes a purchase, our A/B software will make +1 sale to EACH test, so

- +1 sale for varian A in Test 1
- +1 sale for varian B in Test 2
  etc

Is it correct to provide A/B testing using this way?

Note: this is different from providing a multivariative testing on the same page-  it is about testing completely different pages of the website at once, taking into account a user may visit all of them.

Comment: So you're showing one user different pages for every visit?

Comment: No a user gets same pages fr every visit.

Comment: Are the different pages (and their variants) different parts or steps of a typical task? If so then this is not much different from multivariate testing. Other than that, there's no reason you can't be running multiple independent A/B tests.

Comment: a user gets same pages for every visit. What I mean a user may participate in many tests at once, i.e. every page of the site is a single A/B test.

Comment: Whats the difference between the two tests

Comment: The question about attributing a sale to all pages in a session is a common problem for conversion attribution. For example, a site may have both a 'Free Shipping for Orders over $25' promotion and a '10% off all shoes' promotion. When a visitor sees both promotions and purchases more than $25 worth of shoes, is the purchased considered a conversion for both the Free Shipping promotion and the 10% promotion? Every business has a different answer to this question. Here is [Google's explanation of attribution modeling](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1662518) in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your approach:

1. You're only counting the success - that makes it hard to evaluate performance as your a/b changes - e.g. if you change only b to c, you now have twice as many users who saw a then either b or c. You want to count all views as well as conversions
2. Maybe it's OK for your scenario, but you're ignoring the user's flow - you can't tell whether the fact that the user saw a1 had an impact when they saw b2.
    In other words, how do you compare the performance of flow a-b-a-a vs. a-b-b-a ?
   It might seem like this is approach lets you test multiple scenarios at once, but I suspect you are confusing your data. You'll get better results from varying a single test at a time - i.e. ensure each user has only a single variant.